# How to interact and get live stream from camera

Tags: opencv, curl, python-requests, vlc, live-streaming

I have a Garmin VIRB XE camera, and want to get a live stream and interact with camera like getting GPS data. I could get the live stream by VLC media player and also could post commands to the camera by CURL from windows command prompt, but i can't get the live stream using OpenCV and interact with camera using requests library in python.

I can get a live stream from "rtsp://192.168.1.35/livePreviewStream" using VLC media player's network streaming feature, also could interact with camera, for example by "curl --data "{\"command\":\"startRecording\"}" http://192.168.1.35/virb" from command prompt I could start the recording, but the following codes are not working.

```
'''
import simplejson
import requests
url='http://192.168.1.37:80/virb'
data = {'command':'startRecording'}
r=requests.post(url, simplejson.dumps(data))
'''
```

or

```
'''
import cv2
capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.35/livePreviewStream")
'''
```

The post return the error
"ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: http://192.168.1.37:80/virb (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))".
Also the capture could not get any frames.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already confirmed that your RTSP link works with VLC player, here's a IP camera video streaming widget using OpenCV and `cv2.VideoCapture.read()`. This implementation uses threading for obtaining frames in a different thread since `read()` is a blocking operation. By putting this operation into a separate that that just focuses on obtaining frames, it improves performance by I/O latency reduction. I used my own IP camera RTSP stream link. Change `stream_link` to your own IP camera link.

[image]

Depending on your IP camera, your RTSP stream link will vary, here's an example of mine:

```
rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.49:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0
rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp
```

Code

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            self.frame = self.maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(self.frame, width=600)
            cv2.imshow('IP Camera Video Streaming', self.frame)

        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

    # Resizes a image and maintains aspect ratio
    def maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(self, image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
        # Grab the image size and initialize dimensions
        dim = None
        (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

        # Return original image if no need to resize
        if width is None and height is None:
            return image

        # We are resizing height if width is none
        if width is None:
            # Calculate the ratio of the height and construct the dimensions
            r = height / float(h)
            dim = (int(w * r), height)
        # We are resizing width if height is none
        else:
            # Calculate the ratio of the 0idth and construct the dimensions
            r = width / float(w)
            dim = (width, int(h * r))

        # Return the resized image
        return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream_link = 'your stream link!'
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(stream_link)
    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.show_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```